# Facebook login does nothing

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app using Facebook login, already defined the hash using the SHA in facebook.

The app was working fine yesterday, but suddenly stop working, i even restore the code to a previous functional version, but nothing changed.

Every time i try to login just see a loading spinner, which after a second just disappear and nothing happens, i have no errors on the log so i have no idea what's happening.

My Login button is inside a fragment and i'm using this code to manage it

```
public class TourFragmentFacebook  extends Fragment {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
View v;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook , container, false);


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(v.getContext());

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    Log.d("app", "success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("app", "cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("app", "error");
                }
            });


    return v;
}

public static TourFragmentFacebook  newInstance(String text) {

    TourFragmentFacebook f = new TourFragmentFacebook ();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("msg", text);

    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;


}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer, hopefully works for someone else

The onActivityResult method was missing so there's no way to trigger the facebook events, i only added this code and everything is working perfect now

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: in my case, just adding  `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` did the job